# Add Item to the ArrayList of ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, addition

I have an ArrayList of ArrayList like the following code and I'm intended to add one item to an existed arraylist and save it as well as keeping the old arrayList.

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> bigArr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ();
    ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
    arr.add(1);
    arr.add(2);
    arr.add(3);
    bigArr.add(arr);
    ArrayList<Integer> tt = bigArr.get(0);
    tt.add(4);
    bigArr.add(tt);
    System.out.println(bigArr);
```

But the thing is that happens is that it prints  [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]] instead of [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]. Can someone please tell me what should I do to get the second output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `tt` is still pointing to the same arraylist object. It's modifying the same object.

**Solution:** *Make a new list object by copying old list and add item in that list then add list to main list.*

Answer (score 2):

Create two lists instead of reusing the first list.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> bigArr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ();
ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<Integer> ();
arr.add(1);
arr.add(2);
arr.add(3);
bigArr.add(arr);
ArrayList<Integer> tt = new ArrayList<Integer>(arr); // Create a new list based on the elements of the given list
tt.add(4);
bigArr.add(tt);
System.out.println(bigArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

> `Object` type parameter's references are *pass by value* but the
>   ***memory*** location that is pointed by them remains same. So changing anything using any reference variable will affect the same
>   `Object`.

So here `tt` and `arr` is pointing to the same memory location means if you change something in one of them that gets reflected to other as well.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`List`s are objects with mutable state. This means that adding or removing items will change the state of the `List` your variable is pointing to. You create a single `arr = ArrayList<Integer>`, to which you add the values `1, 2, 3`. You then add this list to the `bigArr` list of lists. Now, the first element of `bigArr` and `arr` both point to the same physical object. The moment you retrieve it from `bigArr` and store it in the `tt` variable, you have three ways to access the same list.

What you want, is a new version (copy) of your initial list at `bigArr.get(0)` and add the new value to that list. The easiest way to do this is to use `ArrayList`'s copy constructor when you retrieve it from the `bigArr`. This is already explained in the answer given by Smutje:

```
ArrayList<Integer> tt = new ArrayList<Integer> (arr);
```